# Apply function to all columns of a Polars-DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, python-polars

I know how to apply a function to all columns present in a **Pandas-DataFrame**. However, I have not figured out yet how to achieve this when using a **Polars-DataFrame**.

I checked the [section](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/apply/udfs.html) from the [Polars User Guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/index.html) devoted to this topic, but I have not find the answer. Here I attach a code snippet with my unsuccessful attempts.

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import seaborn as sns

# Loading toy dataset as Pandas DataFrame using Seaborn
df_pd = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# Converting Pandas DataFrame to Polars DataFrame
df_pl = pl.DataFrame(df_pd)

# Dropping the non-numeric column...
df_pd = df_pd.drop(columns='species')                     # ... using Pandas
df_pl = df_pl.drop('species')                             # ... using Polars

# Applying function to the whole DataFrame...
df_pd_new = df_pd.apply(np.log2)                          # ... using Pandas
# df_pl_new = df_pl.apply(np.log2)                        # ... using Polars?

# Applying lambda function to the whole DataFrame...
df_pd_new = df_pd.apply(lambda c: np.log2(c))             # ... using Pandas
# df_pl_new = df_pl.apply(lambda c: np.log2(c))           # ... using Polars?
```

Thanks in advance for your help and your time.

Comment: Can you change the tag to `python-polars`?

Comment: Of course. I just added `python-polars` tag to the original question tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the expression syntax to select all columns with `pl.col("*")/pl.all()` and then `map` the numpy `np.log2(..)` function over the columns.

```py
df.select(
    pl.all().map_batches(np.log2)
)
```

Polars expressions also support numpy universal functions https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html

That means you can pass a polars expression to a numpy `ufunc`:

```py
df.select([
    np.log2(pl.all())
])
```

Note that the difference between an `apply` (now `map_elements`) and a `map` (now `map_batches`) is that `map_elements` would be called upon every numeric value, and the `map_batches` is over the whole `Series`. We choose `map_batches` here, because that would be faster.