# Apply minmax_scale to all columns in polars data frame

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to follow advice [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834912/apply-function-to-all-columns-of-a-polars-dataframe)

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df.select([pl.all().map(np.log2)])
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ a        ┆ b        │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.0      ┆ 2.0      │
│ 1.0      ┆ 2.321928 │
│ 1.584963 ┆ 2.584963 │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

So far, so good. But:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
>>> df.select(pl.all().map(minmax_scale))
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ a               ┆ b               │
│ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] ┆ [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I found a way of converting the `pl.List` back, but it seems strange that this step is needed.

```
df.select(pl.all().map(minmax_scale)).explode(pl.all())
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ 0.5 ┆ 0.5 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Both `minmax_scale` and `np.log2` return arrays, so I would expect the behavior to be the same. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this...

```
minmax_scale(df['a'])
# array([0. , 0.5, 1. ])
```

Now do...

```
np.log2(df['a'])
shape: (3,)
Series: 'a' [f64]
[
    0.0
    1.0
    1.584963
]
```

Notice how with `log2` you get back a Series not an array.
The difference is that `log2` is a true ufunc and so the output remains a series. You can see this directly with:

```
type(np.log2)
# numpy.ufunc

type(minmax_scale)
# function
```

You can do this to avoid the `explode`:

```
df.select(pl.all().map(lambda x: pl.Series(minmax_scale(x))))
```

or you can just define your own func in one line

```
my_minmax_scale = lambda x: pl.Series(minmax_scale(x))
df.select(pl.all().map(my_minmax_scale))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ 0.5 ┆ 0.5 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Very clear! The `lambda x: pl.Series(...)` reads much better to me than using the explode. Would this be the recommended way for any custom function as you show? Let's say I have a function that has several steps, just wrap your `np.array` output in a `pl.Series`

Comment: I don't know if I'm in a position to say anything is "*the* recommended" way to do it but, yes, I think wrapping a custom function output in pl.Series is a good effective way of getting the result you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: why not do the scaling math yourself instead of a `map` or `apply`, so polars can multithread it?

```py
df.select(pl.all().log(2))
```

```py
df.select((pl.all() - pl.all().min()) / (pl.all().max() - pl.all().min()))
```

Comment: This is true for this use case, but "doing the math myself" is not always as straightforward as with these examples.

Comment: I took the question more in the vein of "how to use an arbitrary function" than focusing on the one function they happened to pick out.